# Does 1 distinct eigenvalue guarantee 1 eigenvector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to figure out when 2x2 matrices are not diagonalizable. Right now, my conditions are:

- the matrix has only 1 distinct eigenvalue
- the matrix yields only 1 linearly independent eigenvector

But when I know that there are 2 eigenvalues, can I safely assume that each eigenvalue will have at least 1 linearly independent eigenvector?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By definition, an eigenvalue always has an eigenvector.  And it's easy to prove that eigenvectors for distinct eigenvalues are linearly independent.  If a $2 \times 2$ matrix has only one eigenvalue, there may be either $1$ or $2$ linearly independent eigenvectors.

Comment: Also, if a 2x2 matrix yields one eigenvalue, but two linearly independent eigenvectors, is the matrix still diagonalizable?

Comment: @kompasak Distinct tells you nothing. You want linearly independent or not. Eigenspaces contain many different eigenvectors, what matters is the dimension.

Comment: @kompasak: If a $2 \times 2$ matrix has two linearly independent eigenvectors, regardless of the corresponding eigenvalue, then it is diagonalizable.

Comment: Okay, thank you everyone, I understand it now.